# php post variable comes in surrounded by keyword optional

Tags: php, ios, xcode, swift

Is there a way to strip the posted variable in php or send it differently through swift so the keyword optional isn't surrounding the variable?

For Example:

```
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$query = "SELECT username from users where username = '".$username."' ";
//when echo query output is: SELECT username from users where username = 'Optional("t")' 
//I need to remove Optional so query outputs:
// "SELECT username from users where username = 't'
```

I'm inputting the parameter in swift like this:

```
var post:NSString = "username=\(username)"    
NSLog("PostData: %@",post);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using this:

```
var post: NSString = "username=\(username!)"
```

However, if `username` is nil for some reason then your application will crash. You could surround it in an `if...let` to avoid that.

Comment: No problem @SlopTonio if you could accept my answer that would be great!

Comment: yup, I'm waiting for the 15 minute window to expire so stackoverflow will allow me to accept an answer